# Understanding how label works when elements hidden

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand, how a can label work in conjunction with elements states like `input[type="type=""]:checked` or `input[type=""]:unchecked`.I got a very basic [example](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/yXypyO) which I am trying to work out, but I cannot make the label a circle or square that can have a check mark or unchecked when clicked. What makes the label have that outlook and showing checked and unchecked state? Does the label need to have a width and height? If so do I need to make it a block level element.

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width:0;
  heigh:0;
/*   or display:none? */
}
label{
  position:relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
label:before,
label:after{
  font-size:50px;
}
label:before{
  content: '\f096'; /
   //Can be some good example
}
label:after{
  content: '\f00c';
  //Can be some good example 
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
  content:"check"
  //Can be some good example
}
input[type="checkbox"]:unchecked{
  content:"x"
  //Can be some good example
}
```

Something achievable like [this](https://designmodo.com/demo/css3checkboxes/index.html) but without text next to labels as I want checkbox based on styling.

Comment: so you want to change the content of the LABEL when the checkbox is checked ? i can;t understand exactly what you want to achieve. please be more specific

Comment: How would you check the element, if it is hidden, or has width or height as `0`?

Comment: @Starx — By clicking on the label. That's what labels do.

Comment: @MihaiT I have Edited and put in another link to an example. Although my Question, say what it need i.e. to make a custom checkbox with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a relationship ( css wise ) between your checkbox and the clicked label and change it's content . use css selectors for that. for example `+` or `~`

in the example below i used `:before` and `:after` . `:after` will appear only when the checkbox is :checked. i think this is what you want.

IMPORTANT ! : you set the same `id` to all `checkboxes` this is bad because

1. duplicate ID's are not a good practice when writing HTML
2. you `link` all labels to the same `checkbox` ( all are linked to the checkbox with id `checkbox` . in the below example all have different `ids` and so every label is linked with it's corresponding checkbox

see code below

```css
.img-holder{
   position:relative
}
.checkbox-holder{
  position:absolute;
  background: #fcfff4;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:10px;
  width:50px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
label{
  position:relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
label:before,
label:after{
  font-size:50px;
}
label:before{
  border:2px solid red;
  content:"";
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
   border-radius:100%;
  display:inline-block;
 
}

label:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:green;
  top:-2px;
  left:7px;
  opacity:0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity:1;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  border-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 img-holder">
      <div class="checkbox-holder">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox">
      </div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/480/any/grayscale" alt="">
<!--                 <div class="flex-column justify-content-center">
               <h4 class="add">Added</h4>
               <h4 class="remove">Removed</h4>
          </div> -->
        </div> 
          <div class="col-3 img-holder">
      <div class="checkbox-holder">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
        <label for="checkbox2">
      </div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/480/any/sephia" alt="">
<!--                 <div class="flex-column justify-content-center">
               <h4 class="add">Added</h4>
               <h4 class="remove">Removed</h4>
          </div> -->
        </div> 
                <div class="col-3 img-holder">
      <div class="checkbox-holder">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
        <label for="checkbox3">
      </div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/480/nature/grayscale" alt="">
<!--                 <div class="flex-column justify-content-center">
               <h4 class="add">Added</h4>
               <h4 class="remove">Removed</h4>
          </div> -->
        </div> 
                      <div class="col-3 img-holder">
      <div class="checkbox-holder">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4">
        <label for="checkbox4">
      </div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/480/arch/grayscale" alt="">
<!--                 <div class="flex-column justify-content-center">
               <h4 class="add">Added</h4>
               <h4 class="remove">Removed</h4>
          </div> -->
        </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the content the label itself, but you can control the content of the pseudo element `after` and `before`. You can add the logic of square/circle with something that can represent check and uncheck.

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
  content: "checked";
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9L3p1xt/)

To answer your question in the comment

> How they make funky circle buttons and put a checkbox inside it when one clicks?

You can use CSS animations. The label will already have the check symbol in it but won't have shown in the unchecked state of the input box. And when the element is checked, it will change the opacity to 1, showing the checkbox in an animated way.

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] + label:after {
  content: "checked";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.50s; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s;
  -o-transition: all 0.50s;
  transition: all 0.50s;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9L3p1xt/1/)

Comment: This is a great example, so when I clicked the checkbox the state of input item changes from check to unchecked? I wonder how they make funky circle buttons and put a checkbox inside it when one clicks like [this](https://designmodo.com/demo/css3checkboxes/index.html)

Comment: It does change the state of the input box. No to answer your other question, it's out of context of the question but it has to do with css animations. The label will already have the `check` symbol in it but won't have shown. When the element is checked, it will change the opacity to 1, showing the checkbox in an animated way.

Comment: You can show a faked checkbox by using different contents in the label for the checked and unchecked states, for instance '☑' versus '☐'. Or, put some different graphics in the background of the label. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: @Starx thanks for clearing, one problem is when I have multiple checkboxes when I click any other, the first one get selected [codepen](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/RgPbXK)?

Comment: @Nofel, For me, When I am clicking your demo, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom look and behavior for your checkboxes, you'll have to use some trickery. This involves using CSS to hide your checkboxes and draw a stylable box instead + a `✔` character when your checkbox is selected.

Here's a pretty basic example :

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var checkbox = this.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
      checkbox.checked = checkbox.checked ? false : true;
      this.classList.toggle("selected", checkbox.checked);
  });
}
```

```css
.item {
   padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
   display: block;
   font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }
 
 .item:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .checker {
  border-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width:14px;
  height:14px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -5;
  display: block;
}

.selected .checker {
  border-color: #2199cb;
}

.checker input {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.selected .checker:after {
  color: #ef8730;
  width: 16px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  float: right;
  content: "\2714";
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <label class="checker">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  Item 1
</div>
<div class="item selected">
  <label class="checker">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </label>
  Item 2
</div>
<div class="item">
  <label class="checker">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  Item 3
</div>
```

---

[**See also this JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/x47w0b0z/4/)